# Five handling editors changed in a span of 1 month. What could be the reason?

Tags: peer-review, mathematics, journals, paper-submission, journal-workflow

The submission system shows the name of editor assigned and the name has changed 5 times till now. Its been a month since submission. what could be the reason and does it say anything. Its a mathematics journal.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely it means all the editors invited have declined to handle it. For example, the person most appropriate declined for whatever reason (too busy, sick, etc), and all the others don't feel confident enough to handle it.

In any case there's nothing to do except wait.

Comment: Probably they are too busy because of the pandemic, in particular.